# How to customize nav bar which is from the object library

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

Is there a way we can customize the code below on a nav bar which is from the object library and not a nav bar which is embedded in? I have the code below. It's working on a nav bar that is embedded on my view but when I create my own nav bar from the object library, the code below is no longer working.

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.black
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Chalet-NewYorkNineteenEighty", size: 37.0)!];
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "BG.jpg")!.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets.zero, resizingMode: .stretch), for: .default)
```

Comment: _"when i create my own nav bar"_, and did you create an outlet to try in styling that navbar?

Comment: can we create an outlet for a nav bar?

Comment: As far as I know you can create an outlet for anything. but the best way to find out is to try. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ConnectTheUIToCode.html

Comment: now i think i got it thanks

Comment: how about increasing i ts height ? this frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: height) does not work

Comment: Please post the code you are working with. It seems like the posted code is no longer the one being discussed.

Comment: @AkornDurnKurvirck Can you share how you have created the Navigation bar.?

Answer (score 0):

For the most part I assume you are creating UINavigationBar in xib, in that case IBOutlet wont be UINavigationBarController, give this a try

```
navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
```

navigationBar will be outlet var name...
If this doesn't work more info might help...

Comment: that would cause Use of unresolved identifier 'navigationBar'

Comment: or do i need to create an outlet for that nav bar ?

Comment: yes if you have navbar added to xib and want to use it in code, then you have to create outlet...